# Godot: Xbox Series X Controller recognised as 2 controllers

Tags: godot

I printed out the list of connected joy pads, their names and their guid:

```
func _on_Refresh_pressed():
print(Input.get_connected_joypads())
for x in Input.get_connected_joypads():
    print(Input.get_joy_name(x))
    print(Input.get_joy_guid(x))
```

This is what I got:

```
[0, 1]
XInput Gamepad
__XINPUT_DEVICE__
Xbox Series Controller
030000005e040000130b000000000000
```

You can see two connected joy pads even though I only have one connected. If I disconnect it, both go away and when I connect it, both reappear.
The other controller (Xbox One Wireless Controller) works fine:

```
[0]
XInput Gamepad
__XINPUT_DEVICE__
```

All three connected:

```
[0, 1, 2]
XInput Gamepad
__XINPUT_DEVICE__
XInput Gamepad
__XINPUT_DEVICE__
Xbox Series Controller
030000005e040000130b000000000000
```

In my local multiplayer game, I want to have the player press a button to join the game. With this issue, the game spawns too many players.